# mongo wiredTiger db service start

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I installed the mongodb 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 with wiredTiger configured as the storage engine.

I change /etc/mongodbConfig.conf file -> /etc/mongod.conf

However

```
sudo service mongod start
```

doesn't start MongoDb

```
** service mongod start : error 
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8) utility, e.g. service mongod start
```

But when I use this, I get the following error

```
initctl: Unknown job: mongod

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongod
```

My `mongod.conf`

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/data/wt"
    engine: "wiredTiger"
        wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
            cacheSizeGB: 8
        collectionConfig:
            blockCompressor: snappy
replication:
    oplogSizeMB:  1024
    replSetName: "rs0"
net:
    bindIp: "0.0.0.0"
    port: 27017
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
```

Comment: Well the error logs are a good place to start, but the fair bet is on you did not remove and previous data or convert it in the process. But he question if off-topic for this programming questions site and should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.